# How to simulate a user pressing escape using the Excel COM interface?

Tags: excel, com

I'm working on an Excel add-in and I'm using the Excel COM interface to do automate some testing.  So I'll do something like (all through calls to the Excel COM interface):

- Create a new Excel instance
- Load my XLL add-in
- Create a workbook
- Set some worksheet formulae
- Check that I get the expected results

Now I want to test that my add-in is correctly responding to user cancel requests, i.e. when the user presses escape while a function is calculating the function should abort.

How can I simulate a user pressing escape using the Excel COM interface?

I'm using Python to write my tests, but I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using DDE, that would solve your problem. Another approach is to just write an xll to do it. http://kalx.net/xll is a libray that makes it easy to do this.

Comment: Thanks Keith.  The library you mentioned looks interesting, I'll be taking a closer look at that.  But it's not obvious how I could use that to trigger a user abort/escape event?  I don't mind using DDE (or any other approach).

Comment: DDE let's you send arbitrary key sequences to Excel, including Escape.